# ACAccountType always showing 0 accounts

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have used facebook SDK for authentication with the facebook. When there is no facebook account enabled in settings then by click on the button apps goes to safari for authentication  i.e.

```
if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated)
    {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
        [self updateView];
    }];
```

otherwise if facebook account is enabled then

```
    NSArray *fbAccounts=nil;
    ACAccountType *accountTypeFB;
    if ((_accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]) &&
        (accountTypeFB = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook] ) ){
        fbAccounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFB];
        NSLog(@" %d fbAccounts",[fbAccounts count]);
    }
    if ([fbAccounts count]!=0) {

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"email",
                                nil];

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure");
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@" active session opened ");
                if (self.gotUserDetails)
                {
                    return;
                }
                [self fetchuserinfo];
            }
        }];
    }
```

[image]    }

This image showing the alert to access user info. It is working fine in the simulator. But in device it always goes to safari or in facebook app for authentication even facebook account is enabled in the settings. Please help me out for finding this issue.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you called `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:`?

Comment: @Wain where should I call it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call `accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier` to access the FB account, you need to supply properties. This needs to be done using `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:` and has an asynchronous response.

Move your backup web based auth into a different method, then, check if you can create the account store as you are. If not, call the web method. If you can, try to gain access to the FB account with `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:`. In the completion block you will either have been granted access or you will call the web method.

This code should all run on the main thread. The asynchronous response may be called on a different thread so switch back to the main thread to complete your handling.

---

Fill in the `...` parts.

```
- (void)webAuthorise {...}

- (void)authorise {
if(!_accountStore)
    _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

if (facebookTypeAccount == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed, No account");
    [self webAuthorise];
    return;
}

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                       options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"...", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        if(granted){
                                            NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                            _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                            NSLog(@"Success");

                                            [self ...];
                                        } else {
                                            NSLog(@"Failed, Error: %@", error);

                                            [self webAuthorise];
                                        }
                                        });
                                    }];
}
```

Comment: It is showing this error -[FBSession checkThreadAffinity] NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBSession: should only be used from a single thread'

Comment: It is showing this error -[FBSession checkThreadAffinity] NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBSession: should only be used from a single thread'

Comment: Where else are you trying to interact with FB and on what thread? Technically in the completion block you should switch back to the main thread to be safe.

Comment: If you can upload the code to github / paste / something I can take a look at it later.